# Embedded DB, Java Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, derby

I have some Java knowledge, which I've got during university study (not main discipline). Since then I did't used Java programming for living. 
Recently I've decided to recover the programming skills, so I've started some real java web project with Vaadin. so far some UI is done, now i need save data in DB.
sorry for long introduction, i need you understand my level

Question:
I want to use embedded DB with Vaadin project in Eclipse IDE. I've downloaded derby jar file via Ivy and I stacked here. all tutorials doe's not teach how to link Derby (any) DB to the Web project.

Can you guys give me some clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example of an application that uses Embedded Derby in the distribution package. You can find the related tutorial here:
https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html

Using it is as simple as using any other jdbc driver, only the embedded database is executed within the same process Java.

Here is an example :

```
        /*
         * This connection specifies create=true in the connection URL to
         * cause the database to be created when connecting for the first
         * time. To remove the database, remove the directory derbyDB (the
         * same as the database name) and its contents.
         *
         * The directory derbyDB will be created under the directory that
         * the system property derby.system.home points to, or the current
         * directory (user.dir) if derby.system.home is not set.
         */
        String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";
        String dbName = "derbyDB"; // the name of the database
        props.put("user", "user1");
        props.put("password", "user1");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + dbName
                + ";create=true", props);
        // Then you can use jdbc classes to create and execute your queries
        // For example :
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        // We create a table...
        s.execute("create table location(num int, addr varchar(40))");
```

Comment: Hi, Mostafa, thanks for answer. i doing according the manual http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataToolsPlatform/article.html  but  confusing about where DB location is.  i've downoladed DB and it accesseble from terminal. but still confusing how to add db to my project

Comment: An embedded DB is a minimal database server that runs within your Java application. You don't need to run your database server, because your application will run its own embedded db server. If the embedded is what you want, you really don't have to do anything but initialize a connection. I updated my post to give you an example.

Comment: actually for Embedded DB you have to specify driver 
private static final String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" ;
Class.forName(driver) ; 
but anyway thanks for clue !